# How to avoid SQL injection and XSS attacks when in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, xss

I am using following methods to avoid xss attacks. Is this right way to use it?If not please tell me the correct way to avoid attacks.

```
$first_name=strip_tags($_POST["txt_firstname"]);
```

This for avoiding xss and

```
$fname=filter_var($first_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/")));
if($fname===FALSE)
{
    echo "error";
}
else {
 echo "success;    
}
```

is this good way?

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars()`, this function escapes unwanted tags

Comment: There must be a googol results about this on google.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `filter_input` function with one of the [sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) to remove all unwanted characters, and if this is not enough you may as well validate the input by applying an additional filter like you did with `filter_var`:

```
$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'txt_firstname', 
    FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'txt_email',
    FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

To prevent SQL injections, use [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) for more.

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags` should remove all tags howevever , You can use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)  as an alternative for instance to prevent xss attacks

`$first_name = filter_var($_POST["txt_firstname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

For preventing sql Injection you need to sanitize the POST:

eg:

```
$first_name = filter_var($_POST["txt_firstname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($first_name));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to use a tool like [GUMP](https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP) to clean/filter/sanitize inputs.

```
require "gump.class.php";
//remove the line above if you're going to use composer

$gump = new GUMP();

$_POST = $gump->sanitize($_POST);
```

You can also add your own sanitization filters to filter them and since these tools are specific to handle these problems, in future even if there's a new attack vector found, it will likely be fixed even before you know about them. (as long as you update your tools often)